# Button that is supposed to make div visible, not working

Tags: jquery, html

the button that is supposed make my div visible is not working after adding an effect that allows users to hide the div when clicking outside of it, here is my code.

**The script:**

```
    <script>

     document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    document.getElementById('closelogin').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    </script>

    <script>
    var notH = 1,
      $pop = $('#login').hover(function(){ notH^=1; });

    $(document).on('mouseup keyup', function( e ){
      if(notH||e.which==27) $pop.hide();
    });

    $(document).on('mouseup', function(){
      if(notH)$pop.hide();
    });

    if($pop.is(':visible') && (notH||e.which==27)) $pop.hide();

    </script>
```

**The Div:**

```
    <div id="login" style="visibility:hidden">
    <button id="closelogin">Close</button>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
    <p id="loginshiz">Pick a username</p>
    <button id="go">Go</button>
    </div>
```

**The button:**

```
    <input type="button" id="button" value='Chat'/>
```

I think it has something to do the the visibility:hidden in the div?

Comment: Create a fiddle for this.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Just a suggestion You should try with wrapping your code in [document-ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: looks like your script is executing before the elements are loaded to the dom... add your script in dom ready handler

Comment: [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8y6r/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code you have with

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.id.toLowerCase() === 'button') {
            $('#login').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }else if (e.target.id.toLowerCase() === 'closelogin') {
            $('#login').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }else if ( !$(e.target).closest('#login').length ) {
            $('#login').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    })
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CRJ9A/1/)